# could not create object named "Outlook.Application" 8008005 in VBS

Tags: vba, command-line, vbscript, outlook, admin

I have following script for sending email. When i run this script on **normal cmd window** with command

```
EmailTo.vbs "email" "Subject" "msgBody"
```

I get the email in my inbox, but **when i run this in admin command window** then i get Error:
Error: could not create object named "Outllok.Application"
Code: 8008005
Source: WScript.CreateObject

For Automation, I need to run this vbs in admin command mode. but it does not run in admin mode.

```
Dim ToAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
addAttachment = 0

Dim ol, ns, newMail


ToAddress = Wscript.Arguments(0)
MessageSubject = Wscript.Arguments(1)
MessageBody = Wscript.Arguments(2)

if Wscript.Arguments.Count > 3 Then 
addAttachment=1 
MessageAttachment = Wscript.Arguments(3)
End If

' connect to Outlook
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")

Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & vbCrLf

' validate the recipient, just in case...
Set myRecipient = ns.CreateRecipient(ToAddress)
myRecipient.Resolve
If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
  MsgBox "Unknown recipient"
Else
  newMail.Recipients.Add(ToAddress)
  if addAttachment = 1 Then newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment).Displayname = "Check this out" End If
  newMail.Send
End If

Set ol = Nothing
```

Comment: Try it with `CreateObject` without adding `WScript` in front of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to late bind when creating your mail item:

```
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(0)
```

`olMailItem` enumerates to `0`